# How to move Bottom Navigation View above phone keypad in Android?

Tags: android, keypad, android-bottomnavigationview, behind

[image]

I am using

> com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

My problem is as follows, in Android 12 version, the gray buttons I marked with red in the picture above are the phone's "Home, Back, Recent Apps" keypad. My Bnv is under this keypad. How can i solve this problem.

I can raise it up by giving the margin bottom. However, I wasn't sure how accurate that would be. Because so far I've only encountered this problem in version 12. If I give marginbottom, my buttons will stay very high on all phones. It causes an ugly appearance.

Thanks for your help.